# Can a bad lug nut cause vibrations at 60 mph

Tags: vibration

I replaced the front tires yesterday,  on the way home it started vibrating at 60 mph, I returned to have the balance rechecked and a right front lug sheered off.  Could the bad lug be the cause of the vibration as it has never done that before.

Comment: It's possible, although just one nut failing shouldn't allow for much movement. I'd probably expect it to present as a noise before a vibration.

Comment: one thing could have happened was that all of the lug nuts were loose and somehow all the weight fell on one of the lugs and it broke, or it could be what solar mike has said already

Comment: Do you have spacers or anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

Given the relatively small mass of the lug nut and its small distance from the bearing both radially and axially then I would not think so.

Your vibration is most likely from the new tyres / wheels not being properly balanced. Or, just out of balance with the hub if they were balanced off the vehicle.

Once the lug nut / stud has been replaced then you will know if the vibration continues, but it may not as the wheel could be put back on in a different position compared to when it was taken off. One way to see is to mark the studs which have the valve with them...